# Postgresql upsert with Jooq

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have a `info` table in Postgresql 14.7 with columns `id`, `user_id`, `email`, `phone_number`, `first_name`,
`last_name`, `birth_date`, `gender`, `created`, and `updated`.

I need to perform an upsert operation based on the `user_id` column, but only update the values that are changing.
I am using JOOQ 3.18.1 and my kotlin code looks like this:

```
jooq.insertInto(INFO)
                .set(ID, UUID.randomUUID())
                .set(EMAIL, Info.email)
                .set(PHONE_NUMBER, Info.phoneNumber)
                .set(FIRST_NAME, Info.firstName)
                .set(LAST_NAME, Info.lastName)
                .set(BIRTH_DATE, Info.birthDate)
                .set(GENDER, Info.gender) 
                .set(USER_ID, Info.userId)
             .set(UPDATED, Instant.now())
                .set(CREATED, Instant.now())
                .onConflict(USER_ID)
                .doUpdate()
                .set(EMAIL, Info.email)
                .set(PHONE_NUMBER, Info.phoneNumber)
                .set(FIRST_NAME, Info.firstName)
                .set(LAST_NAME, Info.lastName)
                .set(BIRTH_DATE, Info.birthDate)
                .set(GENDER, Info.gender)
             .set(UPDATED, Instant.now())
                .returning().fetch().size
```

Despite trying to insert the same data twice, I am always getting a return type of 1 and it always performs an insert operation instead of an upsert operation.

Update:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE info
(
    id                          UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id                     UUID        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email                       TEXT        NOT NULL,
    phone_number                TEXT        NOT NULL,
    first_name                  TEXT        NOT NULL,
    last_name                   TEXT        NOT NULL,
    birth_date                  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    gender                      TEXT        NOT NULL,
    created                     TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    updated                     TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);
```

SQL query:

```
insert into "public"."info" (
  "id",
  "email",
  "phone_number",
  "first_name",
  "last_name",
  "birth_date",
  "gender",
  "user_id",
  "updated",
  "created"
)
values (
  '35eb89a7-24aa-4025-8ce0-ed662c74ec63', 
  'abc@abc.com', 
  '+123456789', 
  'TestName', 
  'TestLastName', 
  timestamp with time zone '1993-09-25 04:40:01+00:00', 
  'Male',  
  'e1239b01-32d9-42ec-8596-fb4e00e97b49', 
  timestamp with time zone '2023-04-13 18:30:07.507372+00:00', 
  timestamp with time zone '2023-04-13 18:30:07.509026+00:00'
)
on conflict ("user_id")
do update
set
  "email" = 'abc@abc.com',
  "phone_number" = '+123456789',
  "first_name" = 'TestName',
  "last_name" = 'TestLastName',
  "birth_date" = timestamp with time zone '1993-09-25 04:40:01+00:00',
  "gender" = 'Male',
  "updated" = timestamp with time zone '2023-04-13 18:30:07.579957+00:00'
returning 
  "public"."info"."id",
  "public"."info"."user_id",
  "public"."info"."email",
  "public"."info"."phone_number",
  "public"."info"."first_name",
  "public"."info"."last_name",
  "public"."info"."birth_date",
  "public"."info"."gender",
  "public"."info"."created",
  "public"."info"."updated"
```

Comment: Does you table define a primary/unique constraint on the column `USER_ID`?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` of your table? Also, how did you avoid qualifying the table columns (e.g. `INFO.USER_ID`)? Did you use `with()` or did you specify some constants? In the latter case, are those constants really correct? What SQL query is being produced in the debug logs?

Comment: @LukasEder Yes using `with()`, updated the question with relevant info.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. Do both statements run in parallel transactions, perhaps, rather than in consecutive transactions, or in the same one?

Comment: @LukasEder they are running on a different consecutive transactions.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like something I've encountered before. If you're sure about the transactions, then there must be an even more subtle bug somewhere, not easy to derive from your question. You could try reporting a bug here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose, ideally with a complete reproducer, e.g. based on this template here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve